# is.na() returning TRUE for objects of class "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"

Tags: r, datetime

I am casting two character variables into datetime type using as.POSIXlt() as shown in the code below:

```
var1 <- "26.03.2017 02:00:00" 
var2 <- "26.03.2017 01:58:40" 
t1 <- as.POSIXlt(var1, format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S") 
t2 <- as.POSIXlt(var2, format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

The result is `t1` becomes `"2017-03-26 02:00:00"` and `t2` becomes `"2017-03-26 01:58:40 CET"`.

The output of `is.na(t1)` and `is.na(t2)` are `TRUE` and `FALSE` respectively.

Both `t1` and `t2` are of the class `"POSIXlt" "POSIXt"`.

Where is the problem?

Comment: I edited my question, using tz option solves the problem. Without specifying tz, the problem appears.

Comment: This is a FAQ. Search for daylight savings time in your locale.

Comment: @Roland: Thank you very much :)